# Is it possible to use php Keyword 'use' inside the Php Function?

Tags: php, php-7

Is it possible to use php Keyword 'use' inside the Php Function same as the code below? If I am using 'use' keyword its working fine but I want to use this keyword inside the function. How can I do that please suggest?

```
<?php
public function exportSales()  {
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats- officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xlsx"');
  header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

  $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
  ob_end_clean(); 
  $writer->save('php://output');
}
?>
```

Comment: why would you want to? Keep it clean and neat: namespace declaration -> use -> class -> functions ... also I'm not sure it's valid

Comment: The answer should be apparent by running the code, does the code as you have it work?

Comment: It's not valid, importing is done at compile not runtime so no block scoping for you mister. Either way, why would you want to.

Comment: Actually, i am calling the function inside a class to export the excel file using PHPSpreadsheet library. Code was working file in PHP 5.6 but when i upgrade php to 7. it gives me error.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs No idea How to use namespace

Comment: @mytrendincom a namespace just declares that a file belongs to a certain area, so to speak. E.g. take this folder Category. Inside that you could have 3 folders, Add, Edit and Remove. Inside them you have classes AddController, EditController and RemoveController. Inside that you'd do `namespace App\Controller\Category\[Area]` e.g. `namespace App\Controller\Category\Add` - this now means that in any file I can call App\Controller\Category\Add using use and it will automatically recognise the location of  the file.

Comment: I would recommend [reading the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php). It will make things a lot easier for you going forward.

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid to use `use` keyword inside function. It will give syntax error. As it imports specified namespace, so it should be added after namespace.

> Hierarchy:

```
Namespaces
Use Statements
Class Declaration {
    Function Declarations {
        // code
    }
}
```

For detailed info [Visit here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Comment: I Don't Have idea about namespaces. can you please give a real example instead of Hierarchy... If possible.

Comment: "I Don't Have idea about namespaces" So do some research.  You shouldn't be using `use` statements if you don't know what namespaces are.

Comment: Don't forget that you can use `use` inside classes as well to import traits.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a valid practice. Your code structure should be:

- namespace declaration
- use statements
- classes definition
- functions definition

Just like:

```
namespace foo

Use bar/abc
Use bar/xyz

class foo {
    //class definition
    function bar(){
        //function definition
    }
}
```

You should take a look at the [Import docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php)

**EDIT:**

Example for namespace:

Create your own namespace and a class inside it, with the method export, like:

```
<?php

    namespace myModule

    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
    use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

    class export {
        function exportSales(){
            //function definition
        }
    }
?>
```

And then, you'll be able to use the class inside other code, using the namespace as bellow:

```
<?php

    use myModule\{export}

    function otherFunc(){
        $export = new export()
        $export->exportSales()
    }

?>
```

Comment: That's better :-)